# Laravel routing not completing

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I am somewhat new to Laravel.

I have created a form, submitted it for authorisation but then I am told (by Firefox) the routing will never complete. I know the login has worked as I intercepted it.

Here is my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/',function()
{
     return view('welcome');
})->name('home');


Route::get('/welcome', function () {
      return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/signin',
    [
        'uses' =>'UserController@postSignIn',
        'as' => 'SignIn'
    ]);


Route::get('/dashboard',
    [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'DashBoard',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

Route::get('/logout',
    [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
        'as' => 'Logout'
    ]);
```

and here is the UserController:

```
 class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,
            [
                'email' => 'required | email',
                'password' => 'required'
            ]);

        if (Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) )
        {
            //exit("authorised");
            $message = "you are now logged in";
            return redirect()->route('DashBoard')->with(['successmessage' =>$message]);
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "username\password combination not correct";
            //exit('not - email = '.$request['email'].' password = '. $request['password']);
            return redirect()->back()->with(['errormessage' => $message] );
        }
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    public function getDashboard()
    {
       return redirect()->route('DashBoard');
    }
}
```

As can be seen by what is commented out the authorisation is OK

But I get this from Firefox

***The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.***

Answer (score 0):

Just use to() in your return as

return redirect()->to('DashBoard')->with(['successmessage' =>$message]);

Comment: I tried that and now I get "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:"

Comment: your route is dashboard so use it like this return redirect()->to('dashboard')->with(['successmessage' =>$message]);

Comment: use ->to('/dahsboard') in return

Answer (score 0):

add this to your route

```
Route::get('/signin',
[
    'uses' =>'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'SignIn'
]);
```

Comment: GET. This will defined GET route alongside existing POST route. If somebody wondered what's different in this answer.

Comment: You are right. GET will simply just "GET" the route to your view...while POST is a form action from the form on your view.